# Test SendGrid Upsert Cron Job

Tags: sendgrid

Just trying to get the best method for testing adding/updating contacts via a cronjob without interfering with the current contacts list. Will I need to create a new account specifically for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

If you want to make requests to the API as part of your testing (which I normally advise against, as testing 3rd party services should be unnecessary), and you don't want to affect your data, then you don't need a completely new account, but you can use a [Subuser account](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/subusers).